# Converting .dat files (inconsistent spacings and delimiters) to .csv files

Tags: python, string, dataframe, csv, file

I am trying to read the Computer and Internet Use data from [this link](https://www.census.gov/data/datasets/time-series/demo/cps/cps-supp_cps-repwgt/cps-computer.html). The datasets in 2019 and 2021 are provided as .csv, .dta, and .dat, which is very convenient.

However, the datasets prior to 2019 were in .dat files and had very inconsistent spacings and delimiters as I looked at some columns in the nov21pub.csv file and compared them to the columns in the nov21pub.dat file. The datasets also have negative numbers, NaN, and different numeric lengths in some columns.

Is it possible to convert the .dat files to .csv files by using Python or any other software?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], read [ask], make an attempt at converting the files, and update your question with a specific problem and a [mre]. This will significantly improve the quality of answers.

Comment: After reading nov17rep.dat into a `list` of `str`s, `str.strip()` and `str.split()` get it into a format that can be passed to `csv.writer`.

Comment: `.dat` is a generic extension which only suggests that the file contains "data". Do you have documentation for what the file is supposed to contain or how the file is structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fixed size format. Each field has a fixed number of bytes.

Here, for example, first field has size 5, second 2, third 10, ...

And when a value fills all its size, then, it may appears to be melted, but it doesn't matter since format is not ambiguous.

For example, for those size 5,2,10 (I skip the rest for sake of simplicity), you could have lines

```
    4 2 123456789
12345 9   1234567
1234512    123456
12345121234567890
```

So you may feel that there are 3 numbers in first line, 2 in 3rd, 1 big one in last. But that is not the case. 1st line is 4,2,123456789; 2nd line is 12345,9,1234567; 3rd is 12345,12,123456 (5 first bytes are the 1st number, 2 next the second); 4th row contains 12345,12,1234567890

This is what happens in your file. Especially with the 2nd field (that fits in 2 digits only). Most of the time, it is 1 digit. But in some lines, it is 10,11,12, so 2 digits.

That file is even an "easy" one, because except for those field1/2 fusion from times to times, all other fields could be just separated with spaces (reason why I put "easy" between quotes. In reality, that is on contrary harder, because it makes it harder to understand that it is not just numbers separated by spaces, since for almost the lines it is tho. It numbers with fixed sizes, padded by spaces).

As for the pragmatical question (how to read it):
`np.genfromtxt` has a `delimiter` field. If that delimiter is a string, then it is what separates field. If it is an array of integers, then it is a list of fields size.
In your file, there are obviously 163 fields per lines. 1, on 5 bytes, the 2nd, on 2 bytes, and then 161 on 10 bytes each.

So `delimiter` should be an array `[5,2,10,10,10,10...,10]`. Which you can build that way `[5,2]+[10]*161`

Hence the answer

```py
arr=np.genfromtxt('nov17rep.dat', delimiter=[5,2]+[10]*161, dtype=int)
```